# Change editor skin and content_css

Tags: tinymce

I am new to tinyMCE and trying to implement using react. I was able to add skin and content_Css properties during init. Is there a way to change them dynamically, say on click of a button? Is there an api "editor.replace(skin, newSkinColor)" or similar ?